# Under what circumstances does a theory of infinite sums show that $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 -1 + \dots$ does not have a value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am reading the excellent book *How Not to Be Wrong* by Jordan Ellenberg.

He points out the argument by Guido Grandi from 1703 that:

(1)  Let $T = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots$

(2)  $-T = -1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$

(3)  So, $-T = T - 1$ and $T = \frac{1}{2}$

Ellenberg writes:

> Modern mathematicians would say that if we are to assign the Grandi series
>   a value, it should be $\frac{1}{2}$, because, as it turns out, all
>   interesting theories of infinite sums either give it a value of
>   $\frac{1}{2}$ or decline, like Cauchy's theory, to give it a value at
>   all.

How does one ever establish that all "interesting" theories of infinite sums give it a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ or decline to give it a value at all?

Comment: this is wrong because $T$ is not convergent.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think this is meant to be hinting at any formal statement; it's just an empirical observation that all interesting theories of infinite sums that anyone has come up with have had this property.

Comment: @LuisFelipe ignoring that it is traditionally considered a divergent series, there are many useful applications for giving values to divergent series, such as $1+2+3+4+\dots = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty i = -\frac{1}{12}$.  It is perfectly valid in some contexts to give the sum above the value of $\frac{1}{2}$.  As a result I would hesitate to call it "wrong."

Comment: "All interesting theories of infinite sums" having the operative meaning of those that interest us, which is a subset of those known and in use by us - most notably, zeta regularization.

Comment: @JMoravitz, only if you study physis.

Comment: I should mention that the methods of summation that give $1-1+1-\dotsb=\frac12$ will usually also give $1-1+0+1-1+0+\dotsb=\frac13$, despite the fact that this is just the first series with extra zeroes added.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, but there's so many of those extra zeroes.

Comment: Isn't this missing the point a little? I'm guessing OP is curious about the "theories of the infinite sum" that have been studied, irrespective of the rigour contained therein. For example, I know of the [Cesaro sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), and would be fairly interested in other schemes. Whether they have any meaning or not (I fall on the side of no) is another question entirely.

Comment: How to define $a_1+a_2+\dotsb$? According to Cauchy, it should be defined to be $f(a_1,a_2,\dots)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$. This has lots of nice properties, and some less-nice properties (ex: Riemann rearrangement theorem). Theoretically, _any_ function $\Bbb R^{\omega}\to\Bbb R$ could be a definition of what $a_1+a_2+\dotsb$ means. For example, consider defining $a_1+a_2+\dotsb$ to always be equal to $1$, for all choices of each $a_i$. But that's not a very interesting definition. Cauchy's definition, which I called $f$ above, is generally considered to make the most sense.

Comment: Well, "interesting" is not a rigorous term. So you either know all the different forms of convergence that have been studied and notice what the author says, or you don't.

Comment: We can analytically continue the function $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k x^k = \frac{1}{1+x}$$ to the entire complex plane. $$f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author seems to be using the word "interesting" here as meaning that it has the following properties (where all sums runs $n=1$ to $\infty$ - I use the bare sum to emphasize that we are thinking of it merely as some function taking sequences to numbers):

- If $s'_n$ is $s_n$ with a $0$ appended at the start, then $\sum s_n = \sum s'_n$.
- $\sum a_n+b_n = \sum a_n + \sum b_n$ when both the latter exist.
- If $s_n$ is zero for all $n>N$ then $\sum s_n = s_1+s_2+\ldots + s_N$.

We might also strengthen the last axiom to say that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} s_n$ exists in the ordinary sense, then $\sum s_n$ agrees with it.

The point is that the above three axioms are sufficient to prove that the sum of $s_n=(-1)^{n+1}$ is $\frac{1}2$ if it exists. They are also very natural axioms to adopt to align with our intuition of a sum. So, the word "interesting" here really just means "acts like a sum" to exclude any operations $\sum$ that do something bizarre under ordinary circumstances.

Comment: It's worth noting that there _exist_ summation methods $s$ (i.e. functions $s:{\subseteq\Bbb R^\omega}\to\Bbb R$ that follow your three axioms) such that $s(1,-1,1,-1,\dots)$ is defined. OP has proven that if one exists, $s(1,-1,1,-1,\dots)$ would be equal to $\frac12$, but hasn't proven that such a summation method exists. To prove that one exists, it suffices to give an example of one, such as Cesàro summation.

Comment: Wow.  Great point.  That really addresses my confusion.